# iOS UIWebView issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to load a web page into a webView, but it doesn't load, the webview just show a white screen.

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://199.186.28.133/ls/first.do";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

If I change the urlAddress by something like http://www.google.com, I have no problem. And if I open the url (http://199.186.28.133/ls/first.do) in safari on my iPhone, i can see it with no problem.

BTW: Am working on Xcode 4.2, and my min target is 3.1.3

Any idea?

Comment: http://199.186.28.133/ls/first.do just shows a white page in latest Chrome... Are you sure the website is actually serving some content?

Comment: Your code is correct. Your URL isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just checked this link in iPhone simulator and its showing a white page.. I don't think its serving any content.. if you have access to this page please make sure it have some html content to output

Comment: Yes, URL is working fine. Am really sorry but I cant publish the content cuz is a project of my client. That is the weird thing. I can see it ons safari (in my iPhone) but i cant in the webView

Answer (score 0):

Try to print something inside the UIWebViewDelegate's methods :

For instance :

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
  NSlog(@"didFinishLoad");
  NSString *resultHtml = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavascripFromString:"document.documentElement.innerHTML"];
}
```

And to catch some error :

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView*)webView didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
  NSLog(@"%@",[error localizeDescription]);
}
```